# Having trouble with the mutool trim command

Tags: pdf, trim, mupdf

Can anyone please help with mutool syntax?
I am trying to trim 50points off the left of a media box.
-pages tells me this for all pdf pages....

I try....
trim -mL50 and every possible syntax variation including spaces without any result

Tried all syntax variations

Comment: Thank you. I see the correct syntax now, I had trouble understanding the documentation. But nothing happens when I do it. I am using the 64 bit version on Win11

Comment: 64bit I think, trim seems to have been added since 1.22. Only 1.22.1 and 1.23 available as windows.zip. I have tried both. I think it just doesn't work. I tried Ghostscript without any result either. mutool is possiblly a subset of ghostscript? I have also tried Windows 10. Does anyone have evidence that mutool can trim please?

Comment: Thanks for the offer KJ but it doesn't work with any pdf I try. Does it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to compile a recent version that includes "Trim" (Mutool x32 v 1.23.11).

Anyway here is my observation.

The Command program functionality may not be what is expected, as some objects will be redacted (trimmed) and others may not. Since it works on discreet objects, not a pure clip of linework.

Result for  Top,Right,Bottom,Left combination with a cut line 130 points inside left.

```
mutool trim -b MediaBox -m 0,0,0,+130 -o out.pdf "XpdfReader Frequently Asked Questions.pdf"
```

[image]